# Using Mapkit in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I am using Mapkit in my application, i want to submit the application to appstore, is there any specific procedure need to follow for submitting the mapkit enabled or used application.

please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Google stamp at the bottom left corner of the map view is not being covered up. I once covered it accidentally with a label and got my app rejected. The Google stamp must always be visible.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just submit it. If you used documented APIs, it's app store safe (from that perspective, anyway).